# React Redux state is not being updated when using useSelector inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, setinterval, use-effect

I'm new to react and when I'm updating my state in redux, I'm no able to see my state updated in my component inside a `setInterval`, despite the state in redux is updated correctly (according to a chrome redux plugin); in the `useEffect` in my App component, when `console.log(state)`, I only see the same default state `{number:0}` all the time despite that there is a `setInterval` running and updating the state all the time, I'm using the redux plugin for chrome and the state in redux is being updated, but when trying to query the state using the `useSelector` in my useState, I always get the same state `{number:0}`, so I don't know if there's a fail in the `useSelector`, or there is something that the `setInterval` is not allowing me to see the current state that I can see in the redux chrome plugin. Do you know what could be wrong?

I have the following code:

```
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import allActions from './store/actions/allActions'

const App = () => {

    const state = useSelector(state => state.numberReducer)
    const dispatch = useDispatch();


    useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log(state)
        let currentTimeAsTimestamp = new Date().getTime() + 6*60000;
        if(state.number === 0) {
            const newNumber = state.number +2;
            dispatch(allActions.numberActions.updateNumber("UPDATE_NUMBER", newNumber));
        }else {
            const newNumber = state.number +1;
            dispatch(allActions.numberActions.updateNumber("UPDATE_NUMBER", newNumber));
        }
        }, 1000)
    },[])

    return(
       //some stuff
    )
}
```

Here are my actions:

```
import numberActions from "./numberActions";

const allActions = {
    numberActions,
};

export default allActions;
```

Here is my `updateNumber` action:

```
const updateNumber = (type, newNumber) => {
    return {
        type: "UPDATE_NUMBER",
        newNumber: newNumber,
    };
};

export default {
    updateNumber
};
```

And here is my reducer:

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actionTypes';


export const defaultState = {
    number: 0,
}


const numberReducer= (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "UPDATE_NUMBER":
            console.log("IN UPDATE NUMBER")
            console.log(action);
            return {...state,
                number: action.newNumber
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default numberReducer;
```

Comment: Yes I did all the redux config there, as I said above, the state is updating, but I'm not able to get the current state inside the setInterval

Comment: Try to put a copy of `state` in a ref via `useRef` and `useEffect`, every time the state updates. Then in the `setInterval` function, access `ref.current` instead of the outdated `state`.